# Is there any way to change nuka-carousel dots size to be slightly bigger on React/Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a nuka-carousel that needs a custom dots size. But I have no idea on how to change its sizing and margin.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, in order to increase the chances of receiving a positive response to your questions, please first read the following [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be helpful, for example, if you include in your question, what you have tried for yourself before you asked the question, and what information you have found out from Web searches, or relevant documentation for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS will help you achieve your goal. But please try with the CSS changes in the console and resolve by yourself in the future.

```
.slider-control-bottomcenter button{
  background: black !important;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  width: 26px !important;  // change this according to your requirement 
  height: 26px !important; // change this according to your requirement 
}

.slider-control-bottomcenter svg{
  display: none !important; // as in this situation these is no use of the svg
 }
.slider-control-bottomcenter li{
  margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-react-nuka-carousel-hgyfgz?file=style.css)